# Nesting NSDictionary based on value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdate, nsdictionary

i've data from Library that return this:

```
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:distanceNumber,@"distance",idChallengerN,@"idChallenger",dateFrom, @"date", nil];

[_array addObject:dict];
```

If i print _array this is there result:

```
{
    date = "2015-07-31 14:50:40 +0000";
    distance = "-1";
    idChallenger = 43;
},
    {
    date = "2015-07-31 16:18:57 +0000";
    distance = "-1";
    idChallenger = "-1";
},
    {
    date = "2015-07-31 16:19:05 +0000";
    distance = "-1";
    idChallenger = "-1";
},
```

and it's ok, now I should get each `date` and group this `_array` based on weeks...

I've tried:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];   

for (int i = 0; i<_array.count; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dict = [_array objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDate *date = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"date week = %ld",(long)[dateComponents weekOfYear]);

    NSNumber *weekN = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[dateComponents weekOfYear]];

    if ([tempDic objectForKey:weekN]) {

       //contains
    }
    else{

      //not contains
    }
```

**weekN** return the number of the week in year based on 'date',

now i'm stuck to how group certain data if have the same number of week, like this for example:

```
weekN = 31 {
  {
  idChallenger = 43;
  idChallenger = 22;
  }
}
weekN = 32 {
  {
  idChallenger = 55;
  idChallenger = 21;
  idChallenger = 678;
  }
}
```

thanks to popctrl :

```
NSMutableArray *weekArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    [weekArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}


//This replaces your for loop
for (int i = 0; i<_array.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [_array objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDate *date = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //Notice that I changed NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit to NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear, as NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit has been deprecated
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:date];

    NSMutableArray *innerArray = weekArray[[dateComponents weekOfYear] - 1];
    [innerArray addObject:dict];
}
```

this code produce very well structure, but if I want divide weeks in year before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something that follows the example you've given at the bottom of your post, that would be an array of arrays, where the first array is indexed by date and the inner arrays have no specific order.

If you would like to preserve the initial dictionary data structure, just make the values contained in that array of arrays the dictionary.

EDIT: Here's the code I would use

```
//To initialize the array
NSMutableArray *weekArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
    [weekArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
}


//This replaces your for loop
for (int i = 0; i<_array.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [_array objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDate *date = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //Notice that I changed NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit to NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear, as NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit has been deprecated
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:date];

    NSMutableArray *innerArray = weekArray[[dateComponents weekOfYear] - 1];
    [innerArray addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, can you provide me an example? i don't understand how to create a structure like in my example..

Comment: one more question... any idea to how divide weeks in year? same structure but before there is 2015 = {} 2016={} etc... ?? I know how to get count of the years in my structure, but after i don't know how to add weeks to that year

Comment: Change `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear ` to `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear  | NSCalendarUnitYear`, then use `dateComponents.year` in order to get the year. Then I suppose you could add another array layer of arrays, so array[year] contains array[week] contains array of dictionaries. At that point it may make more sense to convert the year and week arrays to dictionaries, though, which will be more efficient.

Comment: check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836482/group-nsdate-in-weeks-and-order-from-newest-to-oldest thanks